# swift delegate showing nil

Tags: swift, delegates

I have created a .xib and adding this xib to another view. I want to add a delegate method in that .xib file. Here is my code :

.xib file

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomCheckBoxWithCrossDelegate {

    func deleteCustomCheckbox(itemToDelete: String)
}

class CustomCheckBoxWithCross: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkboxLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkboxCrossBtn: UIButton!

    var blockIndexForTheCrossButton: Int = 0
    var delegate: CustomCheckBoxWithCrossDelegate!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib ()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib ()
    }


    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCheckBoxWithCross", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view);
    }


    @IBAction func crossBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Delegate --> \(delegate)")
        delegate!.deleteCustomCheckbox("hello")
    }
}
```

- But in "crossBtnTapped" method I am getting nil value for that delegate.

can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: where did you implement CustomCheckBoxWithCrossDelegate?

Comment: In the other view where I am adding this .xib file.

Comment: can you show the other view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the instance of CustomCheckBoxWithCross in your other class, where you have implemented the protocol. Set delegate property of CustomCheckBoxWithCross instance to self in that file.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't set the delegate property on the other view. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this error several times before, add if delegate is not nil condition.

```
@IBAction func crossBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if delegate != {
    delegate!.deleteCustomCheckbox("hello")
    }
}
```